# Removing spaces in a string, MIPS assembly

Tags: string, assembly, mips, spim

I have a small problem with a program i'm trying to write.  Basically i'm prompting a user for input.  I then count the number of spaces in the string, and display the count.  I also need to print out the original string with spaces removed.

The bug I'm having is when i'm adding characters to my string without spaces, it only adds the first character.  $t2 is the register that is holding the character to be added, and I've checked the registers during run-time to be sure the value there was changing.  I don't know where else to look.

```
    .data
str:        .space 81   # buffer for input string
strNS:      .space 81   # buffer for string w/o spaces
prompt:     .asciiz "Enter a string up to 80 characters\n"
head1:      .asciiz "\nOriginal String:  "
head2:      .asciiz "\nNumber of spaces:  "
head3:      .asciiz "\nWith spaces removed:  "

.text   
main:   
    #print the first prompt and get the input string from console
    li      $v0, 4          #load syscall value to print string into $v0
    la      $a0, prompt     #address of prompt to print
    syscall                 #print prompt to console
    li      $v0, 8          #load syscall value to read input string
    la      $a0, str        #addr of allocated space for input string is now in $a0
    li      $a1, 81
    syscall 

    jal     countSpace

    addi    $t1, $v0, 0     #the count of spaces is in $v0, save it into $t1
    li      $v0, 4          #print header then the count
    la      $a0, head1  
    syscall
    la      $a0, str        #print the original string
    syscall
    la      $a0, head2      #print second header before printing count
    syscall
    li      $v0, 1      
    addi    $a0, $t1, 0     #place the count in $a0
    syscall                 #print the count

    li      $v0, 4
    la      $a0, head3      #print the third header
    syscall
    la      $a0, strNS      #print no spaces string
    syscall


End:    
    li      $v0, 10         #load syscall value for exit
    syscall                 #exit

countSpace:
    la      $s0, strNS
    addi    $sp, $sp, -12   #adjust the stack pointer for saving
    sw      $s0, 8($sp)     #store addr of nospace string
    sw      $ra, 4($sp)     #store return addr on the stack
    sw      $a0, 0($sp)     #store the count on the stack

    #Begin counting spaces
    addi    $t3, $a0, 0     #$t3 has addr of user input
    addi    $t5, $s0, 0     #$t5 has addr of string with no spaces
    li      $t6, 0          #$t6 holds index of string with no spaces 
    li      $t0, 0          #$t0 will hold the count of spaces
    li      $t4, 0          #$t4 holds the index of the string
loop:   
    add     $t1, $t3, $t4   #$t1 = addr of str[i]
    lb      $t2, 0($t1)     #$t2 = character in str[i]
    beq     $t2, $zero, exitCS  #break from loop if $t2 contains null character
    addi    $a0, $t2, 0     #place value to be checked in $a0

    #save values onto stack from temp registers to preserve them
    addi    $sp, $sp, -28   #adjust the stack pointer for 5 values
    sw      $t6, 24($sp)    #save index of string with no spaces
    sw      $t5, 20($sp)    #save addr of string with no spaces
    sw      $t4, 16($sp)    #save index of user input
    sw      $t3, 12($sp)    #save the addr of user input
    sb      $t2, 8($sp)     #save the character in str[i]
    sw      $t1, 4($sp)     #save the address of str[i] 
    sw      $t0, 0($sp)     #save the count of spaces

    jal     isSpace         #result from this jump and link will be in $v0 after call

    #pop saved values from the stack, then reset the pointer
    lw      $t6, 24($sp)
    lw      $t5, 20($sp)
    lw      $t4, 16($sp)
    lw      $t3, 12($sp)
    lb      $t2, 8($sp)
    lw      $t1, 4($sp)
    lw      $t0, 0($sp)
    addi    $sp, $sp, 28    #reset stack pointer
    beq     $v0, $zero, addTo   #if not a space, continue to next character
    addi    $t0, $t0, 1     #if it is a space, increment count
addTo:  
    bne     $v0, $zero, nextChar #If character is a space, branch
    sll     $t7, $t6, 2     #index if nospaces string stores width of 4
    add     $t7, $t7, $t5   #now $t7 points at nospaces[i]
    sb      $t2, 0($t7)     #store the character in the nospaces string
    addi    $t6, $t6, 1     #increment the index of nospaces

nextChar:

    addi    $t4, $t4, 1     #increment the index value
    j       loop            #jump back to loop and continue processing

exitCS:
    addi    $v0, $t0, 0     #count of spaces placed into $v0
    addi    $v1, $t5, 0
    lw      $ra, 4($sp)     #load return addr from the stack
    lw      $a0, 0($sp)     #load value to check from the stack
    addi    $sp, $sp, 8     #reset stack pointer
    jr      $ra             #return

isSpace:
    addi    $sp, $sp, -12   #adjust stack pointer to make room
    sw      $s0, 8($sp)
    sw      $ra, 4($sp)     #store value of return addr onto stack
    sw      $a0, 0($sp)     #store value to check onto stack

    #Check to see if the character is a space
    li      $t0, 32         #ascii value for space character loaded into $t0
    li      $v0, 0          #Set default return to 0, or "not a space character"
    bne     $t0, $a0, endSC #if ascii values match, character is a space
    li      $v0, 1          #$v0 = 1 means it is a space character

endSC:  
    lw      $s0, 8($sp)
    lw      $ra, 4($sp)     #restore return address
    lw      $a0, 0($sp)     #restore addr of str
    addi    $sp, $sp, 12    #reset the stack pointer

end:    jr $ra
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `sll $t7, $t6, 2` to `move $t7, $t6`. There's no need to align anything manually.

[image: MARS debugger]

Here's the data segment of your program after a run with the input `here's some spaces`. Once you see the bug, the fix should be obvious.

Comment: isn't move a pseudocommand?